# What is defaultuser0 and is it safe to delete?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Created a clean installation via latest MCT today and discovered a `defaultuser0` in the list of folders under `C:\Users\`

Does anybody know if it's safe to delete it?

[image: Folder-view of C:\Users]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this potentially was hooked by *NT Authority\System* or *NT Service\TrustedInstaller*:

1. Start a console as *Administrator* or a member of *Administrators*-group.
2. Type in `psexec -s -i cmd.exe` followed by `ENTER`.
3. Type in `lusrmgr.msc` followed by `ENTER`.
4. Remove *defaultuser0* in Local *Users and Groups /Users*.

Of course this means loading the *PsTools* beforehand and placing them into `%systemroot%\System32`.

Comment: This is definitely good information!  However, your question specifically says *"discovered a `defaultuser0` in the list of folders under C:\Users\"* and then asked *"Does anybody know if it's safe to delete it?"*  That clearly emphasizes the folder itself, rather than the user account.  Frankly, there isn't a compelling reason to delete that account and under certain circumstances, [it may actually cause problems](https://superuser.com/a/1335032/650163).

Answer (score 12):

#### What is `defaultuser0`?

> After upgrading to the Anniversary Update, many users have noticed
>   that apart from their regular user accounts, the OS also creates a new
>   Defaultuser0 account. The most interesting part is that this unusual
>   profile cannot be deleted even after performing a clean install.
>
> The Defaultuser0 account bug has been haunting Windows users for a
>   long time. Nobody knows exactly why this account is being created or
>   how users can prevent its creation. The commonly accepted hypothesis
>   suggests the Defaultuser0 profile is created when something goes wrong
>   during the profile creation phase of the main account, and it should
>   be harmless.

Source [Windows 10 Anniversary Update is creating “defaultuser0” profiles](http://windowsreport.com/anniversary-update-defaultuser0/)

---

#### Is it safe to delete it?

Yes. Use one of the following methods.

> **How to get rid of the Defaultuser0 profile**
>
> Solution 1 – simply delete the Defaultusers0 account
>
> Go to Control Panel > User accounts > Delete the profile
>
> Solution 2 – Enable the hidden admin account
>
> - Start your computer using your Windows 10 DVD or USB
> - Select the correct time and keyboard type
> - Click on Repair your computer
> - Select Choose an option > Troubleshoot
> - Click on Command Prompt > type the command `net user administrator /active:yes`
> - Restart your computer > delete the Defaultuser0 account.

Source [Windows 10 Anniversary Update is creating “defaultuser0” profiles](http://windowsreport.com/anniversary-update-defaultuser0/)

Comment: For the first solution suggested, I do not find any other user except mine (Local Administrator account). For the second, I do not have the cd or usb. I must ask my IT department for this; too much trouble...

Comment: @YannisDran "too much trouble... " *Shrug*. I don't think this odd account is harmful...

Comment: you didn't get me. In control panel, I couldn't see a defaultuser0 but only in Users Folder. Finally I deleted it from Windows settings for users (don't remember where exactly) and then I deleted the folder completely. Everything's fine. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Adding to @DavidPostill's answer:

Since, as noted in the comments, defaultuser0 does not show up in any graphical interfaces accessible through either the settings app or the control panel, here is how to get rid of it cleanly:

1. Run the Windows command prompt as Administrator

   - **Option A**: Rightclick on the cmd shortcut in the start menu and select "run as administrator"
   - **Option B**: Hold CRTL+SHIFT and click on any cmd shortcut or the executable itself
   - **Option C**: Open the task manager, selet file -> new task, enter "cmd" and select the run as administrator checkmark
2. Enter `net user defaultuser0 /DELETE`

Comment: **Option A**'s menu is also accessible via hotkey `Win+X`, which I use quite frequently due to a good number of other useful items in there.

Comment: The name of the default user was slightly different for me. In this case, I've just run `net user` to show a list of all users. From there it's possible to choose the exact name.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with 2 folders showing in my C:/users/ directory. They were defaultuser0 and defaultuser100000. I removed both of them and have not had an issue. The user accounts did not show up in my system so I assumed they were just leftovers from some installation process that weren't cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't worry, `defaultuser0` is a normal account created during Windows installation. When your computer goes to setup, you will be automatically logged in to defaultuser0, and will be greeted with the setup screen. After you set up your computer, the account and the user directory will automatically be deleted. Sometimes, the directory or the account doesn't get deleted, so here is how you can manually delete the account yourself.

Open command prompt as an admin and type:

```
net user
```

If `defaultuser0` shows up in the user list, then type:

```
net user /delete defaultuser0
```

Next, open file explorer and go to `C:\Users`, then if the `defaultuser0` directory is present, delete it.

Lastly, open the registry by pressing Win + R and typing:

```
regedit
```

Then, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` and go into each key and check the `ProfileImagePath` entry of each key to see if one of them says `C:\Users\defaultuser0`. If you find the `defaultuser0` remnant, delete the key.

You also don't have to delete it, it's safe for it to stay on your computer.

Hope that helped!