# Use Powershell to copy files to current users logged in and users who login in the future

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I want to create a script that copies a file to all user profiles both who have already logged and for a new user who log into the windows 10 pc.  The location the files should be copied to is Users\username\AppData\Roaming

Please help not great at powershell

Here is my current script. It will copy to existing profiles but I need to add line to copy for new users who login each time

```
$Source = '\\FileShare\FancyConfigurationFiles\Config.xml' 
$Destination = 'C:\users*\AppData\Roaming\' 
Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force}
```

Comment: Why do you need PowerShell for copying one file?

Comment: After deployment of an application I need to push this file to multiple computers and different users login to these machines so I need each profile to get the file once a user has logged on.

Comment: Place the files in the Default User profile and they will be included in every new profile that is created as new people log in.

Comment: I tried putting the file in the defaultuser0 profile and it didn't put the file in any existing profiles music2myyear let alone a newly logged in profile.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I found a script that loads the ntuser.dat and user profiles but that script manipulates the registry for new ad existing users.  I need something just for the file location.

Comment: here is m script.  It will copy to existing profiles but I need to add line to copy for new  users who login each time                                                                   
$Source = '\\FileShare\FancyConfigurationFiles\Config.xml'
$Destination = 'C:\users\*\AppData\Roaming\'
Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force}

Comment: You said "*I tried putting the file in the defaultuser0*".  This is not correct - it should be `Default` not `defaultuser0` which is [something else](https://superuser.com/questions/1152792/what-is-defaultuser0-and-is-it-safe-to-delete).  Try putting it in `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming`.  This should work for new accounts as @music2myear mentioned earlier and your script should work for existing.

Comment: lx07  tried C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming and the file doesn't appear in any other profiles

Comment: Putting it in \default\ will not copy it to any existing profiles. BUT \default\ is used to create the profile folders for any new staff logging in for the first time. You could delete an existing profile on the computer and then it will be recreated from the contents of \default\ as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification  music2myear.   That resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\Default\ contains files and settings used to create profile folders for any accounts logging in to a computer that do not yet have a profile folder in C:\Users\

If you wish for files to be included in the profiles for any new logins, place them in the desired location within this directory structure.

For accounts already logged into the computer that have profile folders, placing files in .\Default\ will not make any change. For these you can either manually or by script place the files into the desired folder, or you can delete the local profile folder (which results in the loss of any data saved locally) which means the profile folder will be created from the .\Default\ folder on the next login.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by asking the registry where the profiles are because they, theoretically, can be customized. In that regard, so can the location of the `AppData\Roaming` folder in each profile, so we should account for that as well to be thorough.

```
# Get the list of profile paths from the registry; since they theoretically can be customized.
$profileListReg = 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList'

# This filters out short SIDs (such as the system account)
$profilesReg = Get-ChildItem $profileListReg | Where-Object { $_.Name.Split('-').Count -gt 4 }

$userProfiles = @{}

# Add Default Profile to hashtable
foreach ($profileReg in $profilesReg) {
    $userProfiles.Add($profilesReg.PSChildName, (Get-ItemProperty ('Registry::{0}' -f $profileReg.Name)).ProfileImagePath)
}

# Add Default Profile to hashtable
#   This will cover new users getting the file
$userProfiles.Add('.DEFAULT', (Get-ItemProperty $profileListReg).Default)

$source = '\\FileShare\FancyConfigurationFiles\Config.xml'
$userShellFoldersReg = 'Registry::HKEY_USERS\{0}\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders'

# Copy Config to each Profile ...
foreach ($userProfile in $userProfiles.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Verbose "$($userProfile.Name): $($userProfile.Value)"

    $userShellFolders = Get-Item ($userShellFoldersReg -f $userProfile.Name)
    $appData = $userShellFolders.GetValue('AppData','','DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')
    Write-Verbose "AppData: ${appData}"

    $destination = $appData.Replace('%USERPROFILE%', $userProfile.Value)
    Write-Verbose "Destination: ${destination}"

    Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination ($destination -f $userProfile) -Force
}
```

You should comment out the `Copy-Item` line at the bottom and turn on verbosity (`$VerbosePreference = 'continue'`) to test and ensure those verbose messages look like what you expect them to.

Note: I do not like using `HKLM:` because interacting with the registry doesn't return full paths with `HKLM:`, it returns `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. So, you have to either string replace those or know that you can just tack `Registry::` on the front of it and get to the path. This is more useful anyway since all hives are not available as PS Drives.