# Is it safe to remove the defaultuser0 account in the Audit Mode?

Tags: windows-10, unattended, windows-audit-mode

I am working with Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB.
I have to prepare customized Windows with the unattended installation.
Everything works fine, but after I deploy the system I can see there is defaultuser0 account. I heard it is okay and it should disappear after a few logons. But it does not.

Is it safe to remove the defaultuser0 account in the Audit Mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is defaultuser0 and is it safe to delete?](https://superuser.com/questions/1152792/what-is-defaultuser0-and-is-it-safe-to-delete)

Comment: Similar, but no the same. I know I can delete defaultuser0 once the system is installed. My question is specifically about Audit Mode because I do not have access to the Windows once it is installed. I am not sure whether defaultuser0 is used between Audit Mode and Windows installation.

Comment: This is an old windows bug. It’s been a while since I’ve seen it. Clean it up in audit mode, that’s when I would do it.